# Sum of a series and tetration?

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory, summation, tetration

Is there an equation that can represent the value of the sum of a series (a sigma) if a tetration takes place inside it?

For example:
$$
\sum\limits_{K=1}\limits^{N} {}^2\!K.
$$
(Here ${}^2\!K = K^K$.)

Thanks! (:

Comment: It is related to [this](https://oeis.org/A001923) integer sequence, although no equation is described there. The following links may be helpful [1](http://ijpam.eu/contents/2007-36-2/9/9.pdf) and [2](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2306261?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

Answer (score 1):

In [this](http://ijpam.eu/contents/2007-36-2/9/9.pdf) paper, it is described that $$\sum_{k = 1}^n k^k = 1 + \sum_{k = 2}^n | \prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq k} (r_i - r_j)^2 | $$ 
where $r_1, \ldots, r_k$ are the roots of $z^k - 1 = 0$.

Comment: This seems a bit trivial since $k^k=\left | \prod_{1\leq i < j \leq k}(r_i-r_j)^2\right|$ according to the paper (which is an interesting identity, but seems to not simplify the sum)

Comment: In my opinion it does simplify the sum a bit (as we do not require powers above $2$, although not that much indeed. I would be surprised (and would love) to see an answer that simplifies the series a lot more.